# variable in bash script not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="eric.sql"
sudo mysqldump -c -u username -p1234 dbname > $VAR
```

But if i run this script I get this error:

```
: Protocol error 3: mysql-export.sh: cannot create eric.sql
```

But if I don't use the variable, but just this:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="eric.sql"
sudo mysqldump -c -u username -p1234 dbname > eric.sql
```

... it is working well. What do I wrong?

Comment: Does your script have DOS line-endings? Dos running `dos2unix` on it fix the problem?

Comment: Side note (main problem is almost certainly as Etan suggests): Always quote your expansions. `> "$var"`, not `> $var`. Otherwise, filenames with whitespace in them won't work. Also: Don't use all-uppercase names for your own variables; by convention, such names are reserved for shell builtins and environment variables; using lower-case names for your own variables means you won't overwrite something that changes how other programs behave by mistake.

Comment: By the way -- out of curiosity, what's the OS and filesystem here? Most UNIX filesystems will allow files to be created with `$'\r'` (that is to say, linefeed characters) in their names, as confusing as the effects of that are.

Comment: Running `bash -x mysql-export.sh`, by the way, is likely to be enlightening.

Comment: try  VAR="$PWD/eric.sql"

Comment: how do you start the script ? as root? (or as a normal user or using sudo)

Comment: @michael501, on what basis would you expect that to be able to have an effect? Keep in mind that the redirection is done by the shell itself, not by `sudo` or `mysqldump`, so any actions they may take to change the directory would have no effect on how the file is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the script had Windows style line breaks (I used notepad). After I used Nano the write the script it was solved.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score -2):

`sudo` can change $PATH variable, depend on your security policy.

```
   -E  The -E (preserve environment) option will override the env_reset
       option in sudoers(5)).  It is only available when either the match-
       ing command has the SETENV tag or the setenv option is set in sudo-
       ers(5).
```

You could add the full path of the file, or remove `sudo` in that script.
This should also work:

```
 sudo PATH="$PATH" mysqldump -c -u username -p1234 dbname > $VAR
```

Comment: `$VAR` is expanded, and stdout opened to point to the destination, before `sudo` is ever started. Thus, `sudo` cannot possibly change how the redirection occurs.

Comment: As for `PATH` -- the problem is not an inability to find/execute `mysqldump`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , no the problem is that it can not write the file in that folder .  Also, look up the `env_reset`  option for sudo.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The shell still opens the file **before** `sudo` is run; `sudo` can't increase privileges for a redirection happening before it ever starts!

Comment: You can test this trivially yourself on your own machine. `sudo echo testing >/testing` (as a regular user without write privileges in `/`); you'll see that it still can't create the file `/testing`, despite the `sudo`.

Comment: Also, the claim that it "can not write the file in that folder" -- why would that happen only if the name were coming from a variable, and not if the name were hardcoded? The answer doesn't fit the details of the question.

Comment: (Finally: Yes, I know about `env_reset`, but `$VAR` is, again, **evaluated _before_ sudo is run**, so `sudo` clearing environment variables is completely irrelevant; moreover, it's a *shell-local* variable, not an *environment* variable, anyhow!)